# Wufoo + Bootstrap Modal + Firefox = Aneurysm

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, wufoo

I have a Wufoo form embedded in a [Bootstrap 3 modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) using the Javascript embed code.

It works great in all browsers except Firefox which sets the height of the iFrame that Wufoo creates and its content to 0.

The resizing seems to happen on document ready. If I trigger the modal before document ready it doesnt seem to do this to the height.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

The code:

```
<div id="formModal" class="modal fade form-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <button type="button" class="close modal-close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
     <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">

      <div id="wufoo-blahblah"></div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      var blahblah;(function(d, t) {
      var s = d.createElement(t), options = {
      'userName':'username',
      'formHash':'blahblah',
      'autoResize':true,
      'height':'320',
      'async':true,
      'host':'wufoo.com',
      'header':'hide',
      'defaultValues':'field21={{ page.url }}',
      'ssl':true};
      s.src = ('https:' == d.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'www.wufoo.com/scripts/embed/form.js';
      s.onload = s.onreadystatechange = function() {
      var rs = this.readyState; if (rs) if (rs != 'complete') if (rs != 'loaded') return;
      try { blahblah = new WufooForm();blahblah.initialize(options);blahblah.display(); } catch (e) {}};
      var scr = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0], par = scr.parentNode; par.insertBefore(s, scr);
      })(document, 'script');</script>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can we get some example code?

Comment: Added code @Jhecht thanks for suggesting.